# How to simplify the syntax needed for 10 >= x >= 1 in BASH conditionals?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I use this BASH script to check if `file.txt` has between 1 and 10 lines:

```
if [[ `wc -l file.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'` -le "10" && `wc -l file.txt | awk '{ print $1}'` -ge "2" ]]
    echo "It has between 1 and 10 lines."
fi
```

This code is too verbose. If I make a change to one part, it is easy to forget to make a change to the repeated part.

Is there a way to simplify the syntax?

Comment: Recent bash versions implement `[[ -s file ]]` which is true if file exists and is non-empty. That covers the 0-line case, since the only 0-line file is an empty file.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to do the whole thing using awk:

```
awk 'END{if(1<=NR&&NR<=10) print "It has between 1 and 10 lines."}' file.txt
```

As pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049639/how-to-simplify-the-syntax-needed-for-10-x-1-in-bash-conditionals/26049656#comment40808785_26049656) (thanks [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)), you might want to prevent awk from processing the rest of your file once it has read 10 lines:

```
awk 'NR>10{exit}END{if(1<=NR&&NR<=10) print "It has between 1 and 10 lines."}' file.txt
```

The `END` block is still processed if `exit` is called, so it is still necessary to have both checks in the `if`.

Alternatively, you could store the result of `wc -l` to a variable in bash:

```
lines=$(wc -l < file.txt)
(( 1 <= lines && lines <= 10)) && echo "It has between 1 and 10 lines."
```

Note that redirecting the file into `wc` means that you just get the number without the filename.

Comment: If you want to protect yourself against huge files, add `NR>10{exit}` to the awk script.

Answer (score 4):

Get the line count, then check it against the range bounds:

```
lc=$(wc -l < file.txt)
if (( 1 <= lc && lc <= 10 )); then
    echo "It has between 1 and 10 lines"
fi
```

Comment: Why did the `[[`'s become `((`'s?

Comment: I used an arithmetic statement instead of a conditional statement to simplify the notation. Because there are no string operations inside `((...))`, you can drop the `$` (because a string must be a variable) and reclaim the comparison operators. You can use `[[ 1 -le $lc && $lc <= 10 ]];` if you like.